# Proof of Monotone Convergence Theorem if $X$ is of finite measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I've been wondering whether the following proof for the monotone convergence theorem, under the assumption that $\mu(X)<\infty$ is correct.

Reminder:

> MCT: Let $(X, F, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f_n \in L^+$ (positive measurable) a sequence of increasing functions that converges pointwise to $f \in L^+$. Then: $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_X{f_n}d\mu = \int_X f d\mu$$

Proof (assuming $\mu(X)<\infty$):

Let $\epsilon>0$.

Let $\epsilon'=\frac{\epsilon}{\mu(X)}$. Then there exists $N>0$ s.t. for all $n>N$

$$f-f_n<\epsilon'$$

since $f>f_n$ for all $n$ and $f_n \to f$.

Integrating on both sides (using monotonicity of the integral), we have:

$$\int_X f-f_n<  \int_X \epsilon'$$

and therefore:

$$\int_X f-f_n< \epsilon'\mu(X)=\epsilon $$

for all $n>N$.

But since there is such an $N>0$ for all $\epsilon>0$ then we have that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N>0$ such that:

$$\int_X f-f_n < \epsilon $$

and so we have proven the claim.

Is this correct? If not, in which case would it be (if any)? If it is, any room for improvement?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are using something stronger than the assumption of pointwise convergence, namely uniform convergence. So, no the proof is not correct.

Comment: @fwd Right... If I use Egoroff then I could split $X$ into two sets - one where it does converge uniformly (and then the bound above holds with $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$) and another of measure $\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ to fix it though, right? (or, generally speaking, Egoroff would fix the proof (?)). Will try to write it up formally in the meanwhile.

Comment: @Anon You can give a nice proof of DCT via Egoroff that way - it's not clear to me that it's going to work for MCT.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Are you able to elaborate on the intuition for that?

Comment: @Anon A key step in the proof of DCT by Egoroff: (Assuming $|f_n|\le g\in L^1$) Choose $\delta>0$ so $\mu(E)<\delta$ implies $\int_E g<\epsilon$. If you're tryingto prove MCT I don't see how you get $\int_Ef_n$ small just because$m(E)$ is small...